# Discrete logarithm problem in base 10. When is it of a very special form?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-logarithms

Doing some personal research I just stumbled upon this problem:

Given an integer $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ that is coprime to 10,  I am interested in whether or not there exists an integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $10^{n} \equiv 91^{\phi(m)-1}$ mod m.

We can further ask for if and how we can construct such a number n and one might also investigate the function you get by varying the number 91. But for now I am mainly interested in this very specific case.

I hope I can gather some inspiration from you guys. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking whether that equation ever has a solution or whether it has a solution for all $m$ such that $(m, 10)=1$?

Comment: @DondeEs: Do you mean $$10^{9} \equiv 91^{\phi(9)-1} \mod 9$$ or $$10^{3} \equiv 91^{\phi(3)-1} \mod 3$$

Comment: Or do you mean $$10^{2} \equiv 91^{\phi(337)-1} \mod 337$$

Comment: ${n \equiv \phi(m)k -1}$,  then ${n+1}$ is divisible by ${\phi(m)}$

Comment: Sorry if I wasn´t clear enough. I want to find all $m$, such that such an $n$ fulfilling the congruency exists. @SSA: With your suggested $n$ the problem becomes $10^{-1} \equiv 91^{\phi(m)-1}$. I do not see how this should solve the problem for more than a finite number of m`s.

Comment: so ${10^n \cdot91 \equiv 1 (mod m)}$, now any multiple of 13 and 7 will give 0( mod m), now for m=3 n=N. I'll try to workout further later this week.